# Android daimajia image slider, i want to clear data onResume method

Tags: android

I am using daimajia library for image sliding and I am calling the functions in onResume method to add images to sliderview, the issue is it is add images as onResume method runs, the same images are multiplying and i want to clear data like arrayList.clear(). Here is my below code,

```
HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();//globally defined

for(int i=0;i<CompanyEventDescription.size();i++)
            {
                String name=CompanyEventDescription.get(i);
                String url=PHOTO_BASE_URL+mobileGroupImage.get(i);
                url_maps.put(name,url);
            }

for(String name : url_maps.keySet()) {
                textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
                // initialize a SliderLayout
                textSliderView
                        .description(name)
                        .image(url_maps.get(name))
                        .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit);

                //add your extra information
                textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
                textSliderView.getBundle()
                        .putString("extra", name);

                mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
            }
```

Comment: where u are adding data in `url_maps` HashMap?

Comment: hi, sorry i forgot to add that code, i have edited it please check

Comment: @rajuh did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you, Thanks :)

initialize  SliderLayout in onCreate

> textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);

after initialize

```
       for(String name : url_maps.keySet())
    {
             textSliderView.description(name)
                    .image(url_maps.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit);

            //add your extra information
            textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
            textSliderView.getBundle().clear();
            textSliderView.getBundle().putString("extra", name);
            mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this , Hope this will help you thanks :)

sliderLayout.removeAllSliders();